# Mouse arrow disappear after computer wake up from suspend mode in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

At ubuntu 13.10. While I wake up my laptop from suspend mode, my mouse arrow disappear. But still can click on items.

Is it a bug? Or where should I configure it?

Comment: Same issue, ubuntu 13:10 with Lenovo Yoga 2 laptop.

Comment: Same for me, but it does not happen every time. I usually log out and then back in.

Comment: Just started happening for me in 16.x. I am using lxde, so Gnome workaround doesn't make sense.

Comment: For people running into this issue now (Jul/Aug 2016), there's a widespread bug affecting Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives -- the discussion can be seen here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604

Answer (score 2):

Running this solved the issue for me:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

If that doesn't work for you, then you can try running these commands as a workaround:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
$ sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same thing - Dell M3800. Fresh install of 13.10

Pointer disappears everytime I suspend by closing the laptop lid, but does NOT disappear if I suspend from the system menu or from a tap of the power button etc.

This appears to be a bug, and a workaround (for me at least) is to suspend from the menu rather than by closing the lid.

Once the pointer is gone, the only way I've been able to get it back is logging out and logging in again.

Answer (score -1):

Start editing the config via:

`sudo nano /etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

and change `IgnoreLid=false` to `IgnoreLid=true`.

Reboot and that's it!!

Comment: -1 Welcome to AskUbuntu.  You are explaining how to disable the suspend-mode without explicitly telling so. Also, the question is about how to get out of suspend-mode with the mouse-pointer still showing. Final note: the question is 2 years old, the original poster will most probably not benefit from it anymore.